# Objective C, make some corner - rounded, not work correctly

Tags: objective-c, tableview

I want to create an item in the table view with topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft - rounded and topLeft leave not rounded. Like this:
[image]

i have added a "rounded code" to my method

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
             cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
 UITableViewCell* cell = [super tableView:tableView
                       cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                GOShadowContainerTableViewCell* commentCell = (GOShadowContainerTableViewCell*) cell; // my base class for cell
    
    // make rounded
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:commentCell.view1.bounds
                                                       byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft| UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerTopLeft
                                                             cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(8.0, 8.0)];
    
        // Create the shape layer and set its path
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        maskLayer.frame = commentCell.view1.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        commentCell.view1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    
        // Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the image view's layer
        view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    
    
    }
```

My UI cell hierarchy

[image]

My problem: when i first load a view, i have list like this:

[image]

then i scoll down then scroll up, and everething is looks like good

[image]

Why it works "strange"? Please help to me to figure out why it doesnt work correctly from first time load tableview

Comment: Because it hasn't "its full size" in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  Maybe add the effect in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: @Larme thanks for the comment, i tried add "rounded" code to `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` but its was working the same

Comment: In `GOShadowContainerTableViewCell`, in `layoutSubviews`, change the mask.

Comment: Remember these cells are cached and reused. You need to reset those layers. Now I am talking of UICollectionViewCell experience, but I believe here it will be the same. Here is what worked with sublayers in UICollectionViewCell. Name you layers something so that you can identify them later. Then when you deque that cell loop through all its sublayers and remove yours and add new ones again. You can also use the cell's prepareForReuse message to clean it up and prepare it for reuse. Otherwise you need to do all of this just once say in the storyboard if possible or in the relevant init message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this..

round the standard backing layer of the Cells View and tell the layer on which corners to apply the rounded mask.

```
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
// kCALayerMinXMinYCorner should be the upper left corner, so not used..
cell.layer.maskedCorners = kCALayerMaxXMinYCorner | kCALayerMinXMaxYCorner | kCALayerMaxXMaxYCorner;
```

did not check .. but looks nice or?

Comment: woow! i spend a lot of time for find a solution, thanks a lot man!